# Running several simple Regression in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

So I have a data set that has 188 rows and 65 columns relating to World development indicators and Birth statistics. I am trying to do a purposeful selection method to create a regression model. The first step of this is to look at all of the individual simple linear models.

my goal is to run regression models in R for for each of my variables against my response. I know I can run `lm(x$v30 ~ x$v1)` which would give the regression for one of the variables. however, i am hoping to be able to do this in one step and pull all of the p values into a table or write them to a CSV.

I was following this but this does not give the P-values in a nice manner:[R loop for Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493011/r-loop-for-variable-names-to-run-linear-regression-model)

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you provide a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't recommend you doing this unless you know what you are doing. Else read about things like selection bias, false discovery rate, etc.

In the following, I am using the iris dataset, and regress the first three columns on the fourth one. You can easily change this to data you have.

Using the broom package isn't mandatory. If you don't want that, remove ``` tidy`` command in the ```lapply` function.

```
library(broom)

list_out <- lapply(colnames(iris)[1:3], function(i)
             tidy(lm(as.formula(paste("Petal.Width ~", i)), data = iris)))

# [[1]]
# term   estimate  std.error statistic      p.value
# 1  (Intercept) -3.2002150 0.25688579 -12.45773 8.141394e-25
# 2 Sepal.Length  0.7529176 0.04353017  17.29645 2.325498e-37
# 
# [[2]]
# term   estimate std.error statistic      p.value
# 1 (Intercept)  3.1568723 0.4130820  7.642242 2.474053e-12
# 2 Sepal.Width -0.6402766 0.1337683 -4.786461 4.073229e-06
# 
# [[3]]
# term   estimate   std.error statistic      p.value
# 1  (Intercept) -0.3630755 0.039761990 -9.131221 4.699798e-16
# 2 Petal.Length  0.4157554 0.009582436 43.387237 4.675004e-86
```

Put them into a data.frame

```
do.call(rbind, list_out)

#          term   estimate   std.error  statistic      p.value
# 1  (Intercept) -3.2002150 0.256885790 -12.457735 8.141394e-25
# 2 Sepal.Length  0.7529176 0.043530170  17.296454 2.325498e-37
# 3  (Intercept)  3.1568723 0.413081984   7.642242 2.474053e-12
# 4  Sepal.Width -0.6402766 0.133768277  -4.786461 4.073229e-06
# 5  (Intercept) -0.3630755 0.039761990  -9.131221 4.699798e-16
# 6 Petal.Length  0.4157554 0.009582436  43.387237 4.675004e-86
```

Comment: Thank you. This ultimately was not my first choice as I wanted to be able to export the P-Values into Excel but I ran the above and manually entered them into Excel. Thank you!

Comment: @Derek I've added a few lines which could have made life easier.