# Is there a way to loop an R classification model while swapping out one variable?

Tags: r, loops, classification

I'm basically trying to do what is described in this question [R Loop for Variable Names to run linear regression model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493011/r-loop-for-variable-names-to-run-linear-regression-model) (i.e. swapping out one independent variable while all others stay constant)

except that I'd like to run a classification model as opposed to a linear regression. Any classification model will do, the simpler the better. Can anyone provide a basic guideline of what this kind of code would look like?

Comment: Asking for recommendations on methods is not really on topic. Perhaps asking first on a stats forum?

Comment: I'm sure there is, however the formulation of your question is to broad for this site, why not try to add what you tried and the problem you faced so we can help you, I suggest you try to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the model you want to apply with one variable, and we'll see how we can generalise form there.