# Regression with for-loop with changing variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run a regression in a loop with variables names changing at each loop. Similar to this setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493011/r-loop-for-variable-names-to-run-linear-regression-model)

At the end, I would like to save the fitted results in a list.

My code is the following:

```
year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)

dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value, female=female, smoker = smoker)

pc<- dta[, c("female", "smoker")]
names_pc <- names(pc)

m_fit <- vector("list", length(names_pc))

for (i in seq_along(names_pc)){
  m <- lm(value ~ year + group + group:names_pc[i], data = dta)
  m_fit[[i]] <- m$fit
}
```

... but something is wrong.  I get the following error message.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = value ~ year + group + group:names_pc[i],  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'names_pc[i]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the formula using `sprintf`/`paste0` :

```
m_fit <- vector("list", length(names_pc))

for (i in seq_along(names_pc)){
  m <- lm(sprintf('value ~ year + group + group:%s', names_pc[i]), data = dta)
  m_fit[[i]] <- m$fit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using **tidyverse**

model

`m <- map(dta[names_pc], ~lm(value ~ year + group + group:.x, data = dta))`

fit

`m_fit <- map(m, ~.x$fit)`