# Linear regression loop with data.table; "Error in data.table column or argument (nr) is NULL"

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, lm

As my dataset is cumbersomely large, I would like to automate some procedures. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036007/linear-regression-loop-for-each-independent-variable-individually-against-depend/25036278?noredirect=1#comment90461596_25036278), which proposes a linear regression loop, which for the dataset `mtcars` is as follows:

```
data.table(mtcars)[, .(MyFits = lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) summary(lm(mpg ~ x)))), .SDcols = -1]
```

I have tried to apply this onto my own dataset with limited succes. I do get the output but there is a problem. The result for some of the Fits is NULL, so when I try to do the suggested operation `Fits[, lapply(MyFits, coef)]` I get:

`Error in data.table column or argument 3 is NULL`

Can I somehow make `Fits[, lapply(MyFits, coef)]`skip the `MyFits` which are `NULL`?

EDIT: Question to which the comments refers has been removed for clarity.

Comment: `Fits = data.table(mtcars)[, .(nm = names(.SD), MyFits = lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) summary(lm(mpg ~ x)))), .SDcols = -1]`?

Comment: Always very nice when people down vote a question without saying why..

Comment: @Frank, Your answer worked by the way, thank you very much!

Comment: Dear Tom, Please fill free to post an answer and accept it if it works.

Comment: @Frank post as answer, please?